# Facebook SDK does not return Instagram media

Tags: facebook, instagram, facebook-php-sdk, instagram-api

I am using new Facebook API
I need to access all info of Instagram user that connected to a Facebook business account.
I have an approved Facebook app with all permissions

```
manage_pages , instagram_basic , page_access
```

Currently by facebook explorer tool or even PHP SDK I can have access to all instagram details such as bio , profile_pic , username but except Media
I  need to know how I can access all media of instagram

I tried to access with these queries, all these return all info except media :

```
me/media
34324098389788871/media
34324098389788871/?fields=media,bio,username
```

also when I try to get instagram details via this query

```
me?fields=instagram_accounts{id,media,username}
```

in explorer area it shows me this message

```
The media field does not exist on the InstagramUser object.
```

Comment: Is it a business account?

Comment: Yes OF course. Facebook does not support non-business accounts

Comment: So you did go via a page to get this id, yes?

Comment: yes. also all other details are provided but media does not returns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook recently made some changes and now taking media is provided
They are working on their Graph API everyday but you can not find any support center any where
By the way here is the URL you can take media of user who connected his instagram account to a Facebook business page

```
graph.facebook.com/v3.2/1544874545788787?fields=media.limit(10)
```